# Installed magento 2.4.6-p1 & added a few products then tried to add a product to cart and got the below error. Any help will be much appreciated

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

[2023-08-07T02:38:55.058044+00:00] main.DEBUG: URI '/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmVzdWlnZW5lcmlzLmNvbS92MjQ2djEvYi1jLWluc3BpcmUtZTE1MC5odG1s/product/1/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add) [] []

[2023-08-07T02:38:55.060439+00:00] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []

Have looked for an answer on google but just cant find anything relating to this issue with Magento 2.4.6-p1 or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check HttpPostActionInterface action in your vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php
Action doesn't accept GET requests so change it to Post there.

Answer (score -1):

1. Clear cache
   `bin/magento c:f`
2. Clear folders generated/code, generated/metadata
   `rm -rf generated/code generated/metadata`
3. Run

   bin/magento setup:di:compile
4. Check after this
5. If it wasn't help, Write in Magento 2 gidhub ticket or create new.
   https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36545